# Ways to Share camera output to multiple AVDs in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, automated-tests

Disclaimer: Beginner at Automated testing

So the use case is to scan a barcode through appium. I have setup multiple avds to run at the same time, but the problem is that avds don't share the same camera output resulting in test failure.
I have tried setting the front and back cameras to webcam0-9 but to no avail, i have tried using other programs like splitcam, OBS etc but it's not working. Any help is appreciated

Using:
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4

Tried setting BOTH Cameras to same numbers, but android studio doesnt detect OBS virtual cam, or any other cam

Edit:
ffmpeg shows the obs virtual cam, but android studio doesn't detect it
[SS for CLI window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWNco.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.